# What’s the word for when someone tells you to do something and that same person reprimands you for it?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I know that there’s a word for it but I cannot remember what it is. I know it can be used in the law e.g. it’s illegal for a police officer to tell a store owner to sell alcohol to a minor and then arrest them. What would be the word for that?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, and our format is very ill-suited to requests for suggestions, recommendations, or other open-ended lists. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) center for additional guidance. We do accept requests for help with vocabulary, but you should see the [guidance for single word requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) before posting.

Comment: There is a huge difference between reprimanding a person and arresting a person.

Comment: the question, and the description of the question, leave 'wiggle rooms' of deception ... and opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word you are looking for is "entrapment."

> Entrapment is a legal term that describes what happens when someone is tricked into committing a crime.
>   [- Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/entrapment)
>
> *The woman's defense was **entrapment**; she claimed that she had no intention of buying contraband until an undercover policeman badgered her into it, and she went along just to get him to leave her alone .*

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Stack Exchange answers are “right” answers, not ideas, suggestions, or opinions. To show that yours is the right answer, please edit to include explanation, context, and supporting facts.  If you are unsure of whether your answer is suitable, please comment it below the question. If you are unsure what the asker is looking for, first ask for clarification in the comment box on the question.

Comment: Lordology - What part of the answer is unclear to you?  The lady asks for a specific word that she has heard before and has forgotten.  She then describes entrapment.  So I answered her question, with a link to a full explanation. Fact is, I am damn sure that "entrapment" is what she is talking about, that it is the *right* answer on the basis of the linked article.  I was just being tactful by recognizing that misinterpetation is *always* possible.

Comment: @remarkl - Note that links have habit of becoming obsolete. It's helpful to quote a selected part or parts of the text from the link that you consider most relevant. Then give the link to show your source.

Comment: @remarkl There is a reason the system flags posts as low quality because of their **length** and **content**.  An answer is expected to be **fully fleshed-out,** with **as much** context, source citations and quotes **as possible.**  This is what makes a good, full and **complete** answer.  One source; one citation is not always enough -- you should always try and write posts to the best of your ability.  For example, you have not included a **quote** explaining where the word could be used.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK  I understand, but situations make cases. This was an easy request for a single word.  I made the informed judgment that this was not a question for the ages, that a link that works today is all the asker needs.  I don't care that some algorithm has flagged my answer as "low quality."  I care whether the asker found it to be such.  Some questions have universal pedagogical importance, and those deserve "high-quality" answers.  This one, in my judgment as a human being in the thick of battle, is not one of them.

Comment: @remarkl For example: GoodJuJu's new answer is not a one or two-line answer; it gives sufficient context and it gives enough definition and explanation.

Comment: @remarkl  *"I care whether the asker found it to be such"* -- StackExchange does not revolve around the asker:  it revolves around the entire community.  *Yes* it is important that the asker's requirements are fulfilled, but other people may find the information insufficient; not fitting StackExchange's requirements.  [This is the design of the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: @Lordology - I understand what you are saying.  I just don't agree that this question needed anything more than I provided, except, arguably, a quotation from the linked source. I don't believe the asker actually described "entrapment," but I do believe that "entrapment" is the word that she was grasping for.  Neither entrapment nor sting operations tell the perp that what they are about to do is legal.  Both are about getting away with a crime, not being tricked into thinking what is illegal is legal.  But this did not seem the place for that discussion. Perhaps I was wrong about that.

Comment: @remarkl Agreed as well.  Perhaps I went a bit too full-throttle on that.  It's just that _so many_ posts these days are just not good enough.  Edit your question to include a quotation and I'll be able to undownvote.

Comment: @Lordology A user named "Lawrence" has already edited it to quote the linked source.  That's fitting, because the "l" at the end of my user name stands for "Lawrence."

Comment: @remarkl I meant a quotation of how it is used.  I've edited.  Could you approve it?

Comment: @Lordology I figured out how to approve your edit, and approved it.  But then I edited it.

Comment: @remarkl  OK.  But in future, you might want to take the example from the source, like I did.

Answer (score 0):

There are also blurred lines between 'entrapment' and a 'sting' operation, commonly just referred to as 'a sting'.

In law enforcement, a sting operation is a deceptive operation designed to catch a person committing a crime. A typical sting will have an undercover law enforcement officer, detective, or co-operative member of the public play a role as criminal partner or potential victim and go along with a suspect's actions to gather evidence of the suspect's wrongdoing.

Entrapment is illegal, a sting operation is legal, but as I said, the lines are blurred.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sting_operation